# Pushing data to webserver using tcp/ip php

Tags: php, tcp

```
<?php
error_reporting(~E_NOTICE);
set_time_limit (0);

$address = ""; //ip here
$port = ; //port number  here
$max_clients = 10;

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, $address , 5000) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

if(!socket_listen ($sock , 10))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket listen OK \n";

echo "Waiting for incoming connections... \n";

//array of client sockets
$client_socks = array();

//array of sockets to read
$read = array();

//start loop to listen for incoming connections and process existing connections
while (true) 
{
    //prepare array of readable client sockets
    $read = array();

    //first socket is the master socket
    $read[0] = $sock;

    //now add the existing client sockets
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++)
    {
        if($client_socks[$i] != null)
        {
            $read[$i+1] = $client_socks[$i];
        }
    }

    //now call select - blocking call
    if(socket_select($read , $write , $except , null) === false)
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    //if ready contains the master socket, then a new connection has come in
    if (in_array($sock, $read)) 
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++)
        {
            if ($client_socks[$i] == null) 
            {
                $client_socks[$i] = socket_accept($sock);

                //display information about the client who is connected
                if(socket_getpeername($client_socks[$i], $address, $port))
                {
                    echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us. \n";
                }

                //Send Welcome message to client
                $message = "Welcome to php socket server version 1.0 \n";
                $message .= "Enter a message and press enter, and i shall reply back \n";


                socket_write($client_socks[$i] , $message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //check each client if they send any data
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++)
    {
        if (in_array($client_socks[$i] , $read))
        {
            $input = socket_read($client_socks[$i] , 1024);

            if ($input == null) 
            {
                //zero length string meaning disconnected, remove and close the socket
                unset($client_socks[$i]);
                socket_close($client_socks[$i]);
            }

            $n = trim($input);

            $output = "OK ... $input";

            echo "Sending output to client \n";

            //send response to client
            socket_write($client_socks[$i] , $output);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I am using this above code to communicate client machine using tcp/ip, communication process is working perfect , I am able read and write client entered  data , now I want push client entered data into webserver(database) and store into database using php and display that data into browser, how can I do ? any help appreciated..

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Retrieving the $input provided by the socket and storing it in database? If yes, you can easily use PDO for database access : http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php

Comment: yes , the &input , which send by client by tcp/ip and I am able to read the display in display in device and I want that data store to into database which is my fields  and my database is table is adding below and i need push as per below fields , please give some idea and some sample..

Comment: this is my  database table  fields
  `id`,  `bill_no` , `bill_amount` ,  `item_name` ,  `quantity` ,  `rate` 
  `amount` ,  `more`  ,  `extra`  ,  `extra1`  
 ;

Comment: what does correspond to the $input you receive ?

Comment: if client send Hi , I m replied with ok and after dsiplay clint message like .. Ok.. Hi

Comment: Yeah but I mean... what is the link between $input and the fields from the database that you listed above?

Comment: Module 1 – Sending Bill Information to Server

Process: Terminal will send the transaction information to server.

Request API: 5001?Cust id|Mach ID|Bill No|Bill Date@Item Name|Item Qty|Item Price|Amt$ Item Name |Item Qty|Item Price|Amt$ Item Name |Item Qty|Item Price| Amt;Discount|Total Amt#

Response API: $Status|Msg#

Status 1 means Success
0 means failure
Msg: Sucess

Comment: we need to do $input into client input by using loop if there any idea please give some suggestion..or else please provide complete socket communication programming to webserver and client..

Answer (score 0):

So, let's admit that your database contains a table storing all of yours inputs. This table could be named "inputs" and be composed of a primary key such as "idInput" (int auto increment) and a classic text field named "input"

What you can do is, where receiving a new input, storing it in this new table. That's why, first, you'll need a database connection through PHP. Let's use PDO :

```
try{
   $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase','root','');
   $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
   $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}catch(PDOException $e){
   exit ('Connection failed');
}
```

Then, right after

```
$n = trim($input);
```

you could do something like :

```
$req = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO inputs(input) VALUES (:input)");
        $req->execute(array(
            "input" => $PDO->quote($input),
            ));
```

Comment: this is my process..Process: Terminal will send the transaction information to server.

Request API: 5001?Cust id|Mach ID|Bill No|Bill Date@Item Name|Item Qty|Item Price|Amt$ Item Name |Item Qty|Item Price|Amt$ Item Name |Item Qty|Item Price| Amt;Discount|Total Amt#

Comment: The above is fields to store into database